# Saving to Google Datastore from Google Dataflow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to save to Google Datastore from Google Dataflow Job it gives me this error

**My Code inside the DoFN is**

```
Datastore datastore= DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        TrackingRequest rq = gson.fromJson(c.element().toString(), TrackingRequest.class);
        Query<Entity> query = Query.entityQueryBuilder().kind("Post").filter(PropertyFilter.eq("postid", rq.postid))
                .build();
        QueryResults<Entity> posts = datastore.run(query);

        if (posts == null || !posts.hasNext()) {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind("Post");
            Key key = keyFactory.newKey(rq.postid);

            Entity entity = Entity.newBuilder(key)
                    .set("appid", rq.appid)
                    .set("postid", rq.postid)
                    .set("title", rq.title)                 
                    .build();               


            datastore.put(entity);
            // c.output(((FullEntity<IncompleteKey>)entity).toPb());
        }
```

**The error is :**

```
exception: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.datastore.v1.Entity$Builder.putProperties(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/datastore/v1/Value;)Lcom/google/datastore/v1/Entity$Builder;
at com.google.cloud.datastore.BaseEntity.toPb(BaseEntity.java:683)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.put(DatastoreImpl.java:337)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreHelper.put(DatastoreHelper.java:55)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.put(DatastoreImpl.java:315)
at com.kryptonz.proccess.KryptonzArchive$RawToObjectConverter.processElement(KryptonzArchive.java:80)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
at
```

Comment: looks like it is not a public method. Checking with Datastore team if there is an alternative. For the time being you could write this method yourself, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/BaseEntity.java#L680

Comment: Filed an issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `toPb` is not a public method. Filed an issue [here](http://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1431).

For the time being you could implement this [method](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/BaseEntity.java#L680) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and so thought the way out might help others too.

I had `google-cloud-datastore` (version `0.11.2-beta`) as my dependency which come up with `datastore-v1-protos-1.0.1`. And I believe the root cause for the mentioned problem was this libs specific class `com.google.datastore.v1.Entity.Builder`, which didn't support neither `putProperties` nor `getPropertiesMap`.

Knowing the problem statement in a better way, helped me to sort the issue conventionally. I had to just make sure to get a new dependency of `datastore-v1-protos` which supports those missing APIs. Hence just added below dependency in my `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.datastore</groupId>
        <artifactId>datastore-v1-protos</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This change might create some protobuf regression, so include below dependency in your `pom.xml` to avoid, if there is any such.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I think this was not actually his problem, but was kind of my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad.. it helped someone

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependency of datastore in pom.xml and the library you import.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
     <version>1.90.0<</version>
  </dependency>

 import com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity;
 import com.google.cloud.datastore.Key;
```

And if the req.post id is the id/Name in the datastore entity then you can directly create key and check if it present in the datastore.

```
Datastore datastore =
  Datastore datastore= DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
  Key key = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind("Post").newKey(rq.postid);
  if(key == null){
        Entity entity = Entity.newBuilder(key)
                .set("appid", rq.appid)
                .set("postid", rq.postid)
                .set("title", rq.title)                 
                .build();   
          datastore.put(entity);   

  }
```